# How should I make supervised classification with mosaic images on GEE?

Tags: javascript, classification, random-forest, google-earth-engine

I [made](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e163f48de99472e02a4f733b3007c244) a supervised classification with only one Sentinel image on GEE and it works perfectly. But when I firstly mosaic some images over my region of interest, error thrown :"Layer error: No data was found in classifier training input."

On Earth Engine User Guide, it says :

> when Earth Engine makes a mosaic of many images, it has to throw out
>   individual image metadata, including the SENSOR_ID property.

I personally guess that's why error thrown because metadata missed, but I don't know how to fix that.

[Here's](https://code.earthengine.google.com/53a69bdbaa8e47422e5f43292fca1171) what I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the line where you clip the scene using a point:

```
.clip(roi) // clip
```

Try to change it and I guess that it will work.